# How can I make the documentation pop-up on hover in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, code-completion

I would like to know how to configure PyCharm so that when I hover over an object or method I get a (formatted) pop-up containing the doc-string. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not using PyCharm myself, but please check **`Settings | Editor | Show quick doc on mouse move`**

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Original feature request ticket: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-66333

If PyCharm you are using is on **131.xxx** branch or newer (can be found on "Help | About") then such option is available under **`Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Show quick doc on mouse move`**.

For some earlier builds (when GUI controls where not yet available) it was possible to activate it by adding `auto.show.quick.doc=true` into `IDE_INSTALL_FOLDER/bin/idea.properties` file.

---

Modern IDE versions have it at **`Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Editing | Show quick documentation on mouse move`** and it is enabled by default:

[image]
*(The screenshot is from PhpStorm but the option name & path is the same across IDEA-based IDEs)*

Comment: Not sure since which version but on version **201.xxx** this option is availiable under **`Settings | Editor | Code Editing | Quick Documentation`**

Comment: @ktv6 201.xxx build? It's 2020.1 version then -- have not tried it yet, waiting for 2020.1.1 bugfix first... But yes, since 2020.1 this option is enabled by default (not sure if it affects existing installations or new ones only).

Comment: @ktv6 it's enabled for me but still doesn't show the docstring

Answer (score 1):

If you are stopped at a breakpoint, PyCharm doesn't show quick documentation on hover even when the box is checked, because it is in "inspect variable on hover" mode. In that case, hold down <kbd>Cmd</kbd> while you hover (on a Mac).

Answer (score 0):

When `Settings | Editor | General | Show quick doc on mouse move` is checked already, look for a window `Documentation`, which be explicitly opened with `Edit | Quick Documentation`.

I had barely noticed that window, but quick doc may show up in there. Instead, to show the doc hovered near the mouse, right-click on the header of the `Documentation` tool window and select `Open as popup`.