# How do I disable the documentation pop-up window on hover in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

Every time I hover over anything with my mouse it opens up this obnoxious documentation page that I have to close everytime. I have searched similar threads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20760753/3924118) and a few other ones that do not address my problem. Turning off the autopopup documentation feature from PyCharm does not solve the mouse hover problem.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem.

For me, disabling the mark at `File/Settings/Editor/General/Show quick documentation on mouse move` worked well. (My Pycharm version is 2016.2.2 Community).

There is also another option `General/CodeCompletion/Autopopup documentation`.

I have disabled both.

Comment: Is there any way to see this view manually after disabling "show quick documentation"?

Comment: Press control-Q on Windows. No idea on Mac.

Answer (score 6):

This is now under
**File/Settings/Editor/General/Code Editing** and then uncheck Show quick documentation on mouse move.

Yes, it's really super annoying. I'm struggling to learn how to use the zeta function with Scipy and still have to deal with this.