# PyCharm auto pop up source code

Tags: pycharm

I've been using Eclipse PyDev, which can show you the source code snippet of an object or a function when your mouse hovers over it.

I'm aware that PyCharm can show a quick documentation snippet on hover: [How can I make docstrings popup on hover in PyCharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760753/how-can-i-make-docstrings-popup-on-hover-in-pycharm)

However, the ability to hover and peek at the *source code* is very important to my workflow. I wonder whether there's a built-in way or a plugin to achieve this?

Comment: Did you try "Go to definition" action? It is called by `Ctrl+B` on Windows and Unix.

Comment: @user2235698 I know that. What I want is a similar behavior from PyDev. In Pydev, you don't need to leave the current line/file to peek at the source snippet by hovering over it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for functions using the "Open quick definition lookup" in the [default keymap](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/pycharm/docs/PyCharm_ReferenceCard.pdf).

The keyboard shortcut is `Ctrl+Shift+I` while cursor is on the function call. However, this only seems to work for definitions and not objects.