# How can I disable quick-show on python doc strings in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, code-completion

I followed the answer given to this question:

[How can I make the documentation pop-up on hover in PyCharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760753/how-can-i-make-the-documentation-pop-up-on-hover-in-pycharm)

But it seems like PyCharm considers the doc string part of the function signature and displays the quick doc popup, when hovering over the doc string with my mouse. Basically showing me a rendered version of what I have underneath.

Is there a way to stop it from doing that? I can't imagine that being intentional.

Comment: Looking to solve this also, it's extremely annoying having it pop up every 2 seconds